# Passing that ball on, where does it end up in?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, exponentiation, power-towers

> $10$ people are seating on chairs around a circular table. These chairs are marked
>   in a clockwise manner. There is a ball on the man’s hand who is seated on $0$
>   marked chair, and the ball will be passed from one man to another in clockwise manner.
>   In first step, the ball goes to $1$ marked chair with $1^1$ turn. In second step, from there, the
>   ball goes to 5 marked chair with $2^2$ turns. In third step, the ball goes to $2$ marked chair by $3^3$
>   turns from $5$ marked chair. By this means, in which chair the ball will be in $2020$<sup>th</sup>
>   step?

Source: [Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad (BdMO)](http://www.matholympiad.org.bd/)

I'm not sure about exactly how many turns are required in the 2020<sup>th</sup> step. The question is a great deal ambiguous. Does the $n$<sup>th</sup> step require $n^n$  turns? Or does the pattern of $1^1, 2^2, 3^3$ repeat itself?

But often in cases like this where there are multiple possibilities for the answer, the one that seems more intuitive and makes more common sense is more likely to be the answer. After solving the problem in both the possible ways, comparing the two different answers should make the answer obvious.

I've already tried to solve the problem [the triad of turns style](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578034/passing-that-ball-on-where-does-it-end-up-in/2578107#2578107) in a self-answer. However, I can't solve it the $n^n$ way; it's too advanced for me. I'm only an 8th grader, you see.

Comment: 2020th step you mean that it will take $2020^{2020}$ turns from it's previous position right?

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana i'm not sure. this is what i'm confused about. my keyboard isn't working anymore, i couldn't write much in the question

Comment: I have got an interesting sequence summation $n^n$ then take modulo 10 it is your position in the nth step

Comment: @CloseVoters if you voting to close this question because the question appears to lack any attempt, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2578107).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sorry for my vote.  I've casted a re-open  vote.  One more to go.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the $n$th step moves the ball $n^n$ places around the circle, we need to find the integer $x$ such that $0 \leq x < 10$ and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2020} n^n \equiv x \pmod{10}.
$$

Note that $$\sum_{n=1}^{2020} n^n \equiv \sum_{n=1}^{2020} a_n \pmod{10},$$
where $0 \leq a_n < 10$ and $n^n \equiv a_n$ for each $n,$
and that $n^n \equiv m^n \pmod{10}$ if $n \equiv m \pmod{10}.$
Also observe the following for any integer $k$:
\begin{align}
3^4 \equiv 7^4 \equiv 9^2 &\equiv 1 \pmod{10}, \\
2^4 \equiv 4^2 \equiv 8^4 &\equiv 6 \pmod{10}, \\
6^k &\equiv 6 \pmod{10}, \\
5^k &\equiv 5 \pmod{10}.
\end{align}

The first $20$ terms of the series have the following equivalences:
\begin{align}
1^1 &\equiv 1 \pmod{10}, \\
2^2 &\equiv 4 \pmod{10}, \\
3^3 &\equiv 7 \pmod{10}, \\
4^4 &\equiv 6 \pmod{10}, \\
5^5 &\equiv 5 \pmod{10}, \\
6^6 &\equiv 6 \pmod{10}, \\
7^7 \equiv (-3)^7 &\equiv 3 \pmod{10}, \\
8^8 \equiv (-2)^8 &\equiv 6 \pmod{10}, \\
9^9 \equiv (-1)^9 &\equiv 9 \pmod{10}, \\
10^{10} \equiv 0^{10} &\equiv 0 \pmod{10}, \\
11^{11} \equiv 1^{11} &\equiv 1 \pmod{10}, \\
12^{12} \equiv 2^{12} &\equiv 6 \pmod{10}, \\
13^{13} \equiv 3^{13} &\equiv 3 \pmod{10}, \\
14^{14} \equiv 4^{14} &\equiv 6 \pmod{10}, \\
15^{15} \equiv 5^{15} &\equiv 5 \pmod{10}, \\
16^{16} \equiv 6^{16} &\equiv 6 \pmod{10}, \\
17^{17} \equiv (-3)^{17} &\equiv 7 \pmod{10}, \\
18^{18} \equiv (-2)^{18} &\equiv 4 \pmod{10}, \\
19^{19} \equiv (-1)^{19} &\equiv 9 \pmod{10}, \\
20^{20} \equiv 0^{20} &\equiv 0 \pmod{10}.
\end{align}

That is, $a_1 = a_{11} = 1,$ $a_2 = a_{18} = 4,$
$a_3 = a_{17} = 7,$ $a_4 = a_6 = a_8 = a_{12} = a_{14} = a_{16} = 6,$
$a_5 = a_{15} = 5,$ $a_7 = a_{13} = 3,$  $a_9 = a_{19} = 9,$ 
and $a_{10} = a_{20} = 0.$

Also note that for any integer $n$ such that $1 \leq n \leq 20$
and any non-negative integer $k,$
$$ (n + 20k)^{n+20k} \equiv n^{n+20k} \equiv n^n \pmod{10}. $$
For $n = 10$ or $20$ this follows since 
$(n + 20k)^{n+20k} \equiv 0^{n+20k} \equiv 0 \pmod{10};$
for $n = 5$ or $15$ because
$(n + 20k)^{n+20k} \equiv 5^{n+20k} \equiv 5 \pmod{10};$
for $n = 2$ or $18$ because
$(n + 20k)^{n+20k} \equiv n^n n^{20k} \equiv 4 n^{20k} \pmod{10}$
and because $n^{20k} \equiv 6 \pmod{10};$
for $n = 4,6,8,12,14$ or $16$ because
$(n + 20k)^{n+20k} \equiv n^n n^{20k} \equiv 6 n^{20k} \pmod{10}$
and because $n^{20k} \equiv 6 \pmod{10};$
and for $n = 1,3,7,9,11,13,17$ or $19$ because
$(n + 20k)^{n+20k} \equiv n^n n^{20k} \pmod{10}$
and because $n^{20k} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}.$

The terms $a_n$ therefore repeat in a cycle of length $20,$ so
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{2020} a_n = 101 \sum_{n=1}^{20} a_n = 101 \times 94
\equiv 4 \pmod{10}.$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3067054/242) for a more general way.

Comment: @BillDubuque Very nice. I wondered whether it would have made more sense to post that answer here and mark the other question as a duplicate, although the newer question is formulated differently.

Comment: The problem is my answer uses methods far beyond 8th grade (= OP level here).

Comment: @BillDubuque That could be a consideration, but people sometimes post answers above an OP's skill level for the benefit of other readers. In this particular case I thought we might have a duplicate question situation. Or perhaps the cross-links that have now been established are good enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of turns is greater than $9$, the actual number of chairs we have to ultimately move through can be calculated by taking modulo $10$.

#### **Triad of $1^1, 2^2, 3^3$**

- > Step #1 = $1^1$ turns
  >   Step #2 = $2^2$ turns
  >   Step #3 = $3^3$ turns
- > Step #4 = $1^1$ turns
  >   Step #5 = $2^2$ turns
  >   Step #6 = $3^3$ turns

$$...$$

The formula here is:

> Step $n$ =
>
> - if   $n$$\mod 3$   equals $1$,  $1^1$ turns
> - if   $n$$\mod 3$   equals $2$,   $2^2$ turns
> - if   $n$$\mod 3$   equals $0$,   $3^3$ turns

The ball's position is furthered by $2$ places at the end of each triad of turns. This is because $1^1+2^2+3^2=32 \equiv 2\pmod {10}$.

You'll see that—
In triad $1$, initially the ball is in chair $0$ and ends up in chair $2$.
In triad $2$, initially the ball is in chair $2$ and ends up in chair $4$.
In triad $3$, initially the ball is in chair $4$ and ends up in chair $6$.

Now how many full triads are there in $2020$ steps?
$2020 \div 3=673$.
$2020 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

This means the ball must have been moved $673\times2$ times.  Modulo 10 gives us $6$. And the extra one step has $1^1$ turn. So the chair holding the ball should be the one marked $7$.

Comment: $$5^5=3125 \equiv 5 \pmod{10}?$$

Comment: @GNUSuppoerter What do you mean? Of course, the statement is true.

Comment: At the first glance, you arrived at a different answer. I don't get triad 2.

Comment: @GNUSupporter What about triad 2 do you not get?

Comment: $n=5\equiv2\pmod3$, but $5^5=3125$ turns doesn't equal to $2^2$ turns

Comment: @GNUSupporter This shows that you didn't get anything at all. Step 1: 1^1, Step 2:2^2, Step 3: 3^3, Step 4: 1^1, Step 5: 2^2...

Comment: Sorry.  I really can't get this.  Moreover, your solution is different from another one.  I don't know why.  IMHO, due to the difficulty of speed reading math and *another solution with a different numerical answer* with *positive* upvote, if you *can't* point out what's wrong with *another answer*, I think that a few people will be patient enough to read your solution unless it's clearly written and easy to follow.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Edited the question.

Comment: To me, this doesn't change anything.  Unless you can point out the mistake in another solution (ball end up at chair $4$), people are unlikely to read yours, provided that they don't see the role of the "triad" with the solution.  $$1+2^2+3^3=32\equiv2\pmod{10} \\ 4^4+5^5+6^6\equiv6+5+6\equiv7\pmod{10}$$
Using numbers from the another solution, in no way we get "In triad 2 (steps 4-6), initially the ball is in chair 2 and ends up in chair 4."

Comment: @GNUSupporter  And you don't really understand. There are two possibilities for the answer. The question is ambiguous. There's absolutely no link between this answer and the other. These are two different ways of interpreting the question.

Comment: Step 4, 5, and 6 don't have $4^4$, $5^5$, and $6^6$ number of turns. The number of turns is still $1+2^2+3^3$.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't believe a MO question can have open answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sum sequence of $n^n$ = $1^1+2^2+3^3+\cdot\cdot\cdot+2020^{2020}$

Because of the  cyclicity of powers:

$$1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^5+6^6+7^7+8^8+9^9\\+10^{10}+11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}+14^{14}+15^{15}+16^{16}+17^{17}+18^{18}+19^{19}\\+20^{20}+21^{21}+22^{22}+23^{23}+24^{24}+25^{25}+26^{26}+27^{27}+28^{28}+29^{19}\\+30^{30}+31^{31}+32^{32}+33^{33}+34^{34}+35^{35}+36^{36}+37^{37}+38^{38}+39^{39}...\mod 10$$
$$=$$
$$1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^1+6^2+7^3+8^4+9^1\\+10^2+11^3+12^4+13^1+14^2+15^3+16^4+17^1+18^2+19^3\\+20^4+21^1+22^2+23^3+24^4+25^1+26^2+27^3+28^4+29^1\\+30^2+31^3+32^4+33^1+34^2+35^3+36^4+37^1+38^2+39^3...\mod 10$$
$$=$$
$$1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^1+6^2+7^3+8^4+9^1\\+0^2+1^3+2^4+3^1+4^2+5^3+6^4+7^1+8^2+9^3\\+0^4+1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^1+6^2+7^3+8^4+9^1\\+0^2+1^3+2^4+3^1+4^2+5^3+6^4+7^1+8^2+9^3$$
$$...\mod 10$$

1. > $\boxed{x^\boxed{1}}=x^5=x^9=x^{13}=\cdot\cdot\cdot=x^{1+4n}$
   >   $\boxed{x^\boxed{2}}=x^6=x^{10}=x^{14}=\cdot\cdot\cdot=x^{2+4n}$
   >   $\boxed{x^\boxed{3}}=x^7=x^{11}=x^{15}=\cdot\cdot\cdot=x^{3+4n}$
   >   $\boxed{x^\boxed{4}}=x^8=x^{12}=x^{16}=\cdot\cdot\cdot=x^{4+4n}$
2. > For any digit $d$ and for any non-negative integer $p$,
   >
   > $d^p \mod 10=(10n+d)^p \mod 10$

The tens in the sequence can be gotten rid of. They don't add upto anything. The last digits are always zero.

$2020-\frac{2020}{10}\\=2020-202\\=1818.$

Now we are left with

$$\color{blue}{1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^1+6^2+7^3+8^4+9^1}\\+\color{red}{1^3+2^4+3^1+4^2+5^3+6^4+7^1+8^2+9^3}\\+\color{blue}{1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^1+6^2+7^3+8^4+9^1}\\+\color{red}{1^3+2^4+3^1+4^2+5^3+6^4+7^1+8^2+9^3}\\...$$

**Every element in the blue-coloured set of numbers has an corresponding element of equal value in the red-coloured set of numbers.**

- $1^1 \equiv 1^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$
- $4^2 \equiv 4^4 \equiv 6 \pmod{10}$
- $5^1 \equiv 5^3 \equiv 5 \pmod{10}$
- $6^2 \equiv 6^4 \equiv 6 \pmod{10}$
- $9^1 \equiv 9^3 \equiv 9 \pmod{10}$
- $2^2 \equiv 8^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{10}$
- $2^4 \equiv 8^4 \equiv 6 \pmod{10}$
- $3^1 \equiv 7^3 \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$
- $3^3 \equiv 7^1 \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$

[image: Last digit of powers of n]

The modulo 10 of the original sum is therefore:

$\frac{1818}{9+9}\times2(1+6+5+6+9+4+6+3+7)\\=\frac{1818}{18}\times2(47)\\=101\times94$

$101\times94 \equiv \boxed{4} \pmod{10}$