# What is the remainder of $1^1$+$2^2$+$3^3$+...+$2020^{2020}$ if divided by 10? (Without Calculator)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there any way to calculate the remainder of $1^1$ + $2^2$ + $3^3$ + ... + $2020^{2020}$ when divided by 10 **without calculator**?

Comment: Probably the first thing that comes to mind to me is to realize that, for any of the numbers of the sum, only its one's digit to the power is the relevant bit with respect to the sum modulo 10. There's probably something more elaborate but that's a start at least.

Comment: See this question and the answer there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578034/

Comment: Also compare with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578034/passing-that-ball-on-where-does-it-end-up-in

Comment: And also a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325529/11619). Quick to find with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%241%5E1%2B2%5E2%2B3%5E3%2B4%5E4%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\bmod 10\!:\ n^{\large\color{#c00}{k+4j}}\equiv n^{\large k}\,$ for $\,k>0,\,$ by $\, n^{\large k+4j}\!-n^{\large k} \equiv n^{\large k}(n^{\large 4j}\!-1) \equiv 0\, $
 by [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3052342/242)

So $\,(n\!+\!20)^{\large n+20}\!\equiv n^{\large\color{#c00}{ n+4\cdot 5}}\!\equiv n^{\large n}\,$ for $\,n>0\,$  so $\!\bmod 10$ the summands repeat in cycles of length $20,\,$ so we need only compute a single cycle sum, which is easy using above, e.g. $\,17^{\large 17}\!\equiv 7^{\large\color{#c00}{ 1+4\cdot 4}}\!\equiv 7^{\large 1}$.

Comment: Note: $\ 20 = {\rm lcm}(10,\color{#c00}4)\,$ explains the cycle length. $\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

You may split it into $\mod 2$ and $\mod 5$:

$\mod 2$:
\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n=1}^{2020}n^n 
  & \equiv_2  &   1010\cdot 1 \\
  & \equiv_2  &   0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$\mod 5$:
\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n=1}^{2020}n^n 
  & \equiv_5  &   \sum_{k=0}^{403}\left((5k+1)^{5k+1} + (5k+2)^{5k+2}+(5k+3)^{5k+3}+(5k+4)^{5k+4} \right)  \\
  & \stackrel{\mbox{Fermat}}{\equiv_5}  &   \sum_{k=0}^{403}\left(1 + 2^{k+2}+3^{k+3}+4^{k+4} \right)\\
  & \equiv_5  &   \sum_{k=0}^{403}\left(1 + 2^{k+2}+(-2)^{k+3}+(-1)^{k+4} \right)\\
  & \equiv_5  &   -1 + \sum_{k=0}^{403}\left(2^{k+2}+(-2)^{k+3}\right) + 0\\
  & \equiv_5  &   -1 - \sum_{k=0}^{403}2^{k+2} \\
  & \equiv_5  &   -1 + \sum_{k=0}^{403}2^{k} \\
  & \equiv_5  &   -1 + 2^{404} - 1 \\
  & \stackrel{\mbox{Fermat}}{\equiv_5}  &   -1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
So, $\sum_{n=1}^{2020}n^n \equiv_2 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{2020}n^n\equiv_5 -1 \equiv_5 4 \Rightarrow \boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{2020}n^n \equiv_{10} 4}$